# How to output lines ( of characters) from a text file into a single line

Tags: python, text, printing

I need help in how to connect multiple lines from a txt file into one single line without **white spaces**

The text file is consisting of 8 lines and each single line has 80 characters, as showing:

[image: a busy cat]
<sub>(source: [gulfup.com](http://im33.gulfup.com/HMGw2.jpg))</sub>

Here is the code that I used, but my problem is that I am not able have all the lines connected with NO white spaces between them:

```
inFile = open ("text.txt","r") # open the text file
line1 = inFile.readline() # read the first line from the text.txt file
line2 = inFile.readline() # read the second line from the text.txt file
line3 = inFile.readline()
line4 = inFile.readline()
line5 = inFile.readline()
line6 = inFile.readline()
line7 = inFile.readline()
line8 = inFile.readline()

print (line1.split("\n")[0], # split each line and print it --- My proplem in this code!
       line2.split("\n")[0],
       line3.split("\n")[0],
       line4.split("\n")[0],
       line5.split("\n")[0],
       line6.split("\n")[0],
       line7.split("\n")[0],
       line8.split("\n")[0])
```

[image: a busy cat]
<sub>(source: [gulfup.com](http://im33.gulfup.com/XfXJ1.jpg))</sub>

Comment: This isn't working because `print` puts spaces between arguments. >>> print 'hi', 'you' hi you Your actual strings don't have any whitespace. There are much better ways to do what you are trying to do, though.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning the poor practice of hard-coding the number of lines in the file (you have 8 calls to `inFile.readline()`). What if you want to add another line to your file? `inFile.readlines()` will return a list of all lines in your file, no matter how many there are*.

Comment: Just wondering, is this a strand of DNA? That's what it seems like (where the letters are the nucleotides).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your file isn't extraordinarily large, you can open the entire contents as one string.

`content = inFile.read()`

Lines of text are split by a special character, `\n`.
If you want everything on one line, remove that character.

`oneLine = content.replace('\n', '')`

Here, I'm replacing every `\n` character with an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

Just read the lines of the file into a list and use `''.join()`:

```
with open ("text.txt","r") as inFile:
    lines = [l.strip() for l in inFile]
    print ''.join(lines)
```

The `.strip()` call removes all whitespace from the start and end of the line, in this case the newline.

Using a comma with the `print` statement does more than just omit the newline, it also prints a space between the arguments.

Comment: Why not structure it so you don't need to know how many lines there are?

Comment: @Tim: I somehow assumed there were more than 8 and the OP only needed the first 8. On re-reading I realize that that's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

```
infile = open("text.txt", "r")
lines = infile.readlines()
merged = ''.join(lines).replace("́\n", "")
```

or even better

```
infile = open("text.txt", "r")
lines = infile.read()
text = lines.replace("\n", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
lines = ''.join(open("text.txt").read().splitlines())
```

lines will be a string comprised of all the lines in the text.txt concatenated to each other without the '\n' character.

Comment: The question says that the text file consists of 8 lines. This answer is within the limitations of the question that was asked.

Answer (score 0):

```
f = open("file", "r")
print "".join(f.read().split())    # Strips all white-spaces
```